# How to update multiple rows in one table (mysql, php, pdo)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

[image: This is my form] the thing is when i left text area blank, i want it to delete that entry

[image: Not delete the whole row]

I have a table in which i want to update primary key (RegNo) and (Name)

```
                              Table students
(Primary Key)                                            (Foreign Key)
 RegNo               Name              Passwd             ProjectID
 f12345              Ali                345                   1
 f12346             Chris               346                   1
 f12347             Ameer               347                   1
```

I am tried few ways,

```
$names = [
       ['reg'=> $_POST['s1_id'], 'name'=> $_POST['s1_name']],
       ['reg'=> $_POST['s2_id'], 'name'=> $_POST['s2_name']], 
       ['reg'=> $_POST['s3_id'], 'name'=> $_POST['s3_name']]
       ]; 

 $query="update students SET Name=:Name WHERE RegNo=:reg And 
 ProjectID='$id'";

 foreach ( $names as $name)
 {
   try
  {

    $stmt = $conn->prepare( $query );  
    $stmt->bindParam(':Name', $name['name']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':reg', $name['reg']);

    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $msg = "Record updated";

    //header("location:adminhome.php");
  }

  catch(PDOException $ex)
   {
      $msg = $ex -> getMessage();
   }
  }
```

Through this way i was able to update Name column only. How i can update both RegNo and Name. I am new to back-end Programming. Don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: If I don't see it completely wrong you are overwriting the same dataset (all with PrejectID=$id) over and over again. Or is there an outer loop that we don't see?

Comment: You are only `SET`ting `Name=:Name`

Comment: @Jeff this code is working fine but its only updating Name. I want to update both RegNo and Name

Comment: @Mehdi yes, my question is how we can set both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? I only added `, RegNo=:reg` this inside the `SET` because reg is already bound I think this is all you need to add.

I updated my answer because it will never match when you send an updated RegNo with your data structure. So you should send two RegNo, the old one, and the new one.

For deleting, I define two queries, one for delete and one for the update. Before we update the results I check inside the `foreach` if the new Students ID (`$name['reg_set']`) is empty, if it is we run the `$query_delete` otherwise we will run `$query_update`

```
$names = [
       ['reg'=> $_POST['s1_id'], 'reg_set'=> $_POST['s1_id_set'], 'name'=> $_POST['s1_name']],
       ['reg'=> $_POST['s2_id'], 'reg_set'=> $_POST['s2_id_set'], 'name'=> $_POST['s2_name']],
       ['reg'=> $_POST['s3_id'], 'reg_set'=> $_POST['s3_id_set'], 'name'=> $_POST['s3_name']]
       ];

 $query_delete="DELETE FROM students  WHERE RegNo=:reg And ProjectID='$id'";

     $query_update="UPDATE students SET Name=:Name, RegNo=:reg_set WHERE RegNo=:reg And
     ProjectID='$id'";

 foreach ( $names as $name)
 {
   try
  {

            if(empty($name['reg_set'])){
                $stmt = $conn->prepare( $query_delete );
                $stmt->bindParam(':Name', $name['name']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':reg', $name['reg']);

                $result = $stmt->execute();
                $msg = "Record deleted";
            }else{
                $stmt = $conn->prepare( $query_update );
                $stmt->bindParam(':Name', $name['name']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':reg', $name['reg']);
                $stmt->bindParam(':reg_set', $name['reg_set']);


                $result = $stmt->execute();
                $msg = "Record updated";
            }


    //header("location:adminhome.php");
  }

  catch(PDOException $ex)
   {
      $msg = $ex -> getMessage();
   }
  }
```

Comment: from where i will get "  $_POST['s1_id_set']" this value?

Comment: @J Quest are you there?

Comment: Yes, I am, Uehm you have to send it with the form. From where do you receive s1_id ?

Comment: <input type="text"  id="s1_id" name="s1_id"  value="<?php echo $RegNo[0];?>" class="form-control"/>

Comment: @J Quest from a form i send this value

Comment: So, inside that form you should add `name='s1_id_set'` here you can fill the new RegNo. But you should also send the old RegNo. And you can simply doing that with; `<input type="hidden" id="s1_id" name="s1_id" value="<?php echo $RegNo[0];?>" />` 

So you got two fields all for just the RegNo, one hidden one visible. The Visible will send the new/updated RegNo and the hidden one should send the old one just for your WHERE condition.

Comment: @J Quest Thank you so much! its worked :) sorry for late reply.

Comment: @J Quest, if you dont mind can ask you another question?

Comment: @Mr_question sure

Comment: @J Quest check below i have question that while updating, at times you have update two students and sometimes one student, and delete the other student?

Comment: So you want inside the same code also the delete function?

Comment: So, if student ID is blank then remove?

Comment: @J Quest yes that way

Comment: @J Quest Thanks for your time. But delete statement is not deleting the entire row . When i see the page for students list for particular project it display empty spaces. I posted photo above.

Comment: @Mr_question I think it's because of the (Foreign Key), But I can't answer that one. Would you vote my answer up?

Comment: But when i write delete query at phpmyadmin server it works there.

Comment: Please note that the DELETE FROM command cannot delete any rows of data that would violate FOREIGN KEY or other constraints.

I dont know why, you should ask someone else related to this.